# Supposedly simple integration question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

It has been a fair while since I've done any mathematics (took a semester off after the long summer break), and therefore maybe I am missing something obvious, but I cannot seem to solve the following: $$\int_1^e \frac{(\ln|x|)^2}{4x}dx.$$ Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Since $x$ goes from $1$ to $e$ you could omit the absolute value sign.

Comment: You can drop the absolute value bars since $|x|=x$ for $1<x<e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $u$ = $\ln x$ and then $du = \frac{1}{x} dx$.

I think you can take it from here. For more information about what is happening: [click!](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcTwoDIRECTORY/usubdirectory/USubstitution.html)

Comment: It was simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Your integral is in the form $$\int f(x)^2 \cdot f'(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Since $x>0$, then the integral can be written as
$$
\frac14\int_1^{\large e}\frac{\ln^2x}{x}\ dx.
$$
Now put $u=\ln x\;\Rightarrow\;du=\dfrac1x\ dx$.